# Changing which browser MS Access Web Browser Control uses from IE to Chrome

Tags: vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control, ms-access-2016

I have an MS Access database application that uses the Web Browser Control on a few different forms. My company is switching a few systems that can only be accessed with Chrome and do not work in IE. Is there a way, using VBA or other method, to change the browser application that MS Access uses to display the webpage on a form?

Comment: Not an answer to your exact request but you can automate chrome with selenium basic.

Comment: I think the Web Browser Control is built around IE so it may not be possible or take significant code. Another option is to just open the actual Chrome browser using something like this:

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://yourwebpage.com

Comment: @K753 Thank you for that idea. I do have that code in there for opening up a webpage, there is just some forms that pull in client data and it updates the Control with the client in our CRM2011. It allows me to work side by side. Now that we are going to CRM Dynamics 365, that can only work in Chrome. .... I may just need to cut the tie and change my forms.

Comment: @QHarr, Thank you for that, but it would not help in my situation. I appreciate you letting me know though.

Comment: QHarr is right. The integrated browser control always uses IE. However, you can find/implement ActiveX controls for other browsers, but this is nontrivial. Also note that the integrated browser control runs in IE 7 compatibility mode by default. Switching that to IE 10/IE 11 often improves the experience a lot already.

Comment: I've automated Chrome and (older versions of) Firefox from Access, via Selenium, as described in this article.    https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-firefox-or-chrome-with-vba-and-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

I THINK I have THE answer. I put together an MS Access form containing the web browser control -- in 2009 or 2010. It worked great! I cycled GPS address selection using Google Maps processor. IE with Compatibility Control "LET" Chrome-Maps do it's thing.
BUT THEN ... Windows 10 brings "improved" MS Windows Internet. I had little demand for 4 years -- UNTIL NOW!
Enough already!!!  Windows10 Settings - Default Internet Browser .. CHANGE to CHROME -- TA-DA!  I did a full reboot of my computer -- just to make sure. Without any OTHER code changes, my MS Access form WITH WebBrowserControl - once again - works perfectly as it did when it last worked correctly for me.
I really did NOT want to switch away from Edge being default browser. But BING Maps does not allow me to implement my needed Mapping activity. Please be careful to examine as many of your possible consequences as you can.

Comment: Please try to write answers, not stories. Meaning: Try to concentrate on the essence of the solution. And do format paragraphs (by adding empty lines in between).